# Wordpress high CPU usage - cPanel

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, pid

I have checked my "Process Manager" in cPanel and found out that 70+ is getting used by mysql. I'm fairly new to this so want to understand what could be wrong.

[Screenshot from cPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99ihC.jpg)

I have 12 active WordPress installs. 4-5 of them are getting some traffic to websites.

My server:

```
Total processors: 8
Processor #1
Vendor
GenuineIntel
Name
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
Speed
2593.748 MHz
Cache
20480 KB
```

Memory: `14213784k/15728640k available`

```
(5362k kernel code, 1049096k absent, 465760k reserved, 6990k data, 1340k init)
```

Runs on Linux.

I want to try to understand what's the issue, cause usage from this server is too big for only few websites.

Comment: `I have 12 active WordPress installs.` That would be a good place to start looking...

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using, try to disable XML-RPC. See how you can do it here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-disable-xml-rpc-in-wordpress/

Also, try to enable some caching plugin.

Comment: Will try this out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Optimization and security / CMS WordPress
https://irebu.com/optimization-and-security-cms-wordpress

Comment: looks like a shameless plug